# Get facebook newsfeed in my custom Android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am creating an Android app. I integrated Facebook SDK version 4.2.0. I successfully completed Facebook login and I got the Profile Details (Profile Picture,Profile Name etc).

My requirement is that I need to bring all the news feeds from the user's account to my app. Is there any way to achieve this? I searched a lot for this.. but nothing turned up that fitted my requirement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
new GraphRequest(
   AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
   "/me",
   null,
   HttpMethod.GET,
   new GraphRequest.Callback() {
       public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
       }
   }
```

).executeAsync();

This way you can directly use it with the facebook sdk

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname& with this link you can try your requests

saw that if you ask for example the posts you need a specific access token!

Comment: Peter it is working...it returns userprofile details....but i want facebook feeds

Comment: don't forget to add the fields you are querying e.g fields=id,name,about

Comment: Mark it as solved I will have a look at how to achieve this!

Comment: and posts to get the posts /me/posts

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&

Comment: still I am getting nukk values

Comment: poste the response please

Comment: add the fields you are looking for e.g fields=name,id

Answer (score 0):

The graph API should do the trick!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Comment: Thanks Peter..But the url returns like this {
   "data": [
      
   ]
}..What should I do??

Comment: Great! If my answer solves your question please mark it as solved! Regarding the other issue can you send your request url

Comment: Hi Peter..this is my url https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3//me/feed?access_token=CAAPaZABlsBn4BADd2tG4eedZCvAiRS9tbHJzRZA12fv8rb6WK1dp1joGGVOadVkcjZBAyZC6dTmtlNlBYpmwVjS37yQJGaFff39ZBXptoe1an63M6fYYiFKivhsmz8hOtr698m7ZA00uZBzd0OVhnVyTJBdlg4k8yiqmUY5m8ABu3aki1gWk7CEvdaZB3XNs3Nl9m3ueo4xvoN8xCXRLumIp0qKzQK927NdCZAIz9XV8T68gZDZD&format=json&sdk=android

Comment: Where does the access token come from?

Comment: After Fb login (register callback) I wrote this  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() Here got access token

Comment: So you are definitely using the access token returned by the login?

Comment: in button clicklisntner i wrote this code testing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        "/me/feed",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                            } }
                ).executeAsync();
            }
        });